# Tools used in the development of stackoverflow.com, airbnb.com, google+, facebook.com etc?

Tags: php, html, graphics

What tools, programming languages and internet technologies may possibly have been used in the development of stackoverflow.com, airbnb.com, google+, facebook.com etc?

I, actually, want to give users of my apps similar smooth, aesthetically sound and reliable experience.

Comment: HTML! CSS! JavaScript! PHP! SQL!

Comment: Such experiences have more to do with the level of code quality, rather than the technologies and frameworks used.

Comment: This question is way too broad.

Comment: Google+ is NOT running on PHP... or lets just say I'd be suprised, those live updates certainly are not (it keeps an ajax request open on the background indefinitly so the server can send content to make the browser update)

Comment: since all are completely different, it's safe to answer - EVERYTHING was used

Comment: They use some `1`'s and `0`'s, with the occasional nightmare `2` sprinkled in to keep everyone on their toes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tools are rather irrelevant – what you know is what you know. Some languages may make the process easier, but most are at least sufficient to do the trick if you know how.

The aesthetics depend on countless hours of design and revision work. The reliability depends more on hardware and operating system stability than your software. Using good design techniques and workflows, and being able to meet project deadlines efficiently with a minimum of defects is far more important.

To answer what could be used:

- Apache
- PHP
- HTML
- JavaScript/AJAX
- Rails
- SQL
- Perl
- etc. etc. etc.

The list is endless. The more you know, the more you see and try, the better feel you'll have for developing these large projects.

I have a social networking site that I developed as a project. Originally in XHTML and PHP with no javascript, it's grown to incorporate HTML5, AJAX, Flex, and other tools just as the technology and the features have grown. It's nice to aim for the pinnacle – the most popular site – and try to duplicate it; sadly, by the time you catch up, they've left you in the dust. Start small and grow into the development and do it *your* way.

Answer (score 2):

How good a website is, does not depend on the tools it was made with. It simply doesn't matter if you're using Netbeans or Eclipse, SVN or git, GIMP or Photoshop. What does matter is, that you know your tools and can work with them.

But first you need a really good idea, which is the hardest step.